# SVG icon in Android Studio throws error "STRING_TOO_LARGE"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, utf-8

I have a new Android Studio project with one TextView and one ImageViev in the main activity. When I add an image as SVG, from project resources, then the problem occurs, when trying to build a project. When I delete ImageView I will not get the error after the build.

I have tried to find a solution, but only two solutions can be found on Google, where you can downgrade the Gradle version, but that didn`t help in my situation.

One more solution I found, that I can try to separate some layers from SVG into more than one SVG and than use more than one SVG on top of each other. But I have a lot of them and that will take months to do that.

I also tried to compress SVG with some online tools, but none of them helped.

The result should be, build without any errors with my SVG added to the main activity. Now, I have receiving Android Gradle plugin error:

string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'.

Comment: You can optimize your vector drawable with this tool https://github.com/alexjlockwood/avocado. So your path length is reduced. If the length is still large enough think if you can optimize the path and reduce it in the original svg itself

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I forgot to mention that, I have used some online tools to compress SVG, but none of them worked for me. But, I will try this tool and will let you know if it helps.

Comment: i agree with using avocado, i've used it before and it definitely works

Comment: As I understand that SVG must be not more than 32kb, but mine SVG file is 134.775kb and Avocado optimized it to 125.25kb, so the error is still there after optimization. Before I was working with React-native, I thought that was pain in the azz with SVG, but it seems, that it was much easier than in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I also have just faced this issue and have resolved it by optimizing my svg in this website: https://svgoptimizer.com/
After, optimizing your svg, try it, if it doesn't help, optimize the optimized svg one more time!

Hope it helps you!